# while hide some accumatica screen from site map getting another process error

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We want to hide some acumatica screen from site map while published our customization package.

For this I have Write code in master data Plugin its working fine for single tenant but in case of multiple tenant it's not working.

getting below error in case of publish multiple tenant

Error: Another process has updated the 'MUIScreen' record. Your changes will be lost.

Below is code:--

SiteMapMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance(); List siteNodeList = EWPMMasterDataHelper.GetSiteNodesData();

foreach(EWPMSiteMapDTO siteNodeDTO in siteNodeList) {

foreach(PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap siteMap in PXSelect<PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap,
Where<PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap.screenID>>>>.Select(graph, siteNodeDTO.ScreenID)) {

```
// Check Screen is exits on site node or not.
if(siteMap != null && (siteMap.Workspaces == ProductionOrderworkSpaceID.ToString() || siteMap.Workspaces == BillOfMaterialWorkSpaceID.ToString())) {
    siteMap.Workspaces = emptyWorkSpaceID.ToString();
    graph.SiteMap.Update(siteMap);
}
```

}
} graph.Actions.PressSave();